# Partial view not getting updated on click of button ruby rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views

From file **soul.html.erb** , partial view called at the time of page load

```
<%= render 'contact_options_soul_d' %>
```

In file **contact_options_soul_d.html.erb** partial view  looks like this -

```
<div id="contact-option">
<div id= 'un-authenticated' data-access-api-result = <%= @valid_ticket %> %></div>
</div>
```

On click of a button a Rest call happens in controller and partial view is called from partial_create.js.erb

```
  def  partial_create
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
      end
      return
    end
```

File partial_create.js.erb

```
$('#contact-option').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'rhythm/contact_options_soul_d') %>')
```

My Question is - partial view is called , breakpoint hits and new value of @valid_ticket also gets updated, but view is not getting updated as webpage still looks same even after updation.(View remains same when checked in browser inspect)
Please help!!!

Comment: Is the partial name `partial.js.erb` or `partial_create.js.erb`? It must be the latter.

Comment: It is partial_create.js.erb . I use ruby mine , so nothing could go wrong in terms of placing file and file name , is what I believe :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to exactly the way you're doing it, but you could always render it in the controller and return that on "respond_to", then on Ajax success use the returned value to substitute the html:

```
def  partial_create
    html = (render_to_string partial: 'rhythm/contact_options_soul_d', locals: { if_you_need: variables_in_partial })

    respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render json: { new_html: html, success: true } }
    end
    return
end
```

then on your JS code (this with jQuery):

```
function soul_searching(parameters) {
$.ajax({
  url: "YOUR/POST/ROUTE",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  data: {
    any_parameters: 'you_need_to_pass_to_controller'
  },
  success: function(data) {
    $('#contact-option').html(data['new_html']);
  },
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    //DO SOMETHING
  }
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to prepend partials with an underscore. For example:
**_contact_options_soul_d.html.erb**

Note: You only need to do this to the file name. You can still call the partial with

```
<%= render partial: 'contact_options_soul_d.html.erb' %>
```

Also make sure you're referencing the path if the partial is in a separate folder.